# Prevent site down when importing data from large XML file

Tags: multisite, import, xml

## **Scenario :**

I am using WordPress multisite. I have created plugin which imports sample data from theme folder (I have pattern given in plugin which fetches file)

And then I have defined default theme for new blogs, so when someone creates blog and logs into admin panel, plugin starts working.

### **Problem :**

When importing large files (around 15MB or more) which have causes site down until server process that file. Only after success or an error I am able to open site.

Till it shows loading page. And I have checked site from [isup.me](http://isup.me) , it shows site is down.

### Question :

So Is there any other way to work around to prevent site down until it process importing. Or Can I show maintenance mode till successful import operation ?

Comment: Define "down"? What precisely happens? What your hosting support says happens, is it running out of allocated resources or something?

Comment: by "down" I want to say website doesn't open, just loading image in title bar,I have checked with online tools also. Web hosting says nothing. No errors of memory allocation. It continues importing data even I close tab and renames functions.php importer plugin also.

Comment: How can I kill that running process in server ?